# How to check permission on multiple file directories - linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, permissions

After running a script on linux command line I get a .txt file. When looking at the .txt file, I see lots of numbers and in what file directories to find them.

For instance:

```
usr/lib/tc/pareto.dist
123455324

usr/bin/python2.7
4564745

/etc/rpc
845669
```

I know I can show the permission for one file directory with `ls -l "some_file`.
But how do I show the permission for more than one file directory in a txt.file?

For example:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me   me   1097374 Sep 26 18:48 some_file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  316848 Feb 27  2000 /usr/bin
 ..
```

Answer (score 1):

this can help you.

```
grep "/" yourFile | xargs ls -l
```

or

```
ls -l `grep "/" yourFile`
```